# How to access "count" value as dict/property in sqlalchemy with group_by?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am making a very simple query using ORM SQLAlchemy, in which I expect to get a column (type) as well as its occurences for each value (`count` with `group by`).

I can access the `type` column by accessing the `type` property on the `server` object (as shown in the code provided).

I can also access the `count` column by accessing the index 0 on the `server` object.

My question is: is there a simple way to access the `count` column as a dict/property? For example: server.count

I've extensively inspected the `server` object using `dir()`, but I couldn't find any properties that would return the `count` value.

```
class Server(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'servers'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = Column(String)
    method = Column(String)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Server(type='%s', method='%s')>" % (self.type, self.method)

session = Session()

servers = session.query(func.count(Server.type), Server.type).group_by(Server.type).all()

for server in servers:
    print(server[0], server.type)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer to my question after re-reading [the official ORM tutorial](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/tutorial.html#querying)

All I need to do is to set a label for the column for which there's no corresponding property in my class.

So, instead of doing this:

```
servers = session.query(func.count(Server.type), Server.type).group_by(Server.type).all()
```

I should do that:

```
servers = session.query(func.count(Server.type).label('total_count'), Server.type).group_by(Server.type).all()
```

Then I can access the `total_count` property (provided by the `label` function):

```
for server in servers:
    print(server.type, server.total_count)
```